# What is the purpose of specifying the non concrete Repository in the DI wiring?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>;)); 
services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
```

Above code does the DI wiring in .net core

I have a repository (Repository), and concrete repositories (for example: ProductRepository) that inherits from this repository.

Then in the respective serivice class I inject the respective repository. The service class is injected into controller.

What is the purpose of following line - that is - What is the purpose of specifying the non concrete Repository in the DI wiring?

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>;));
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the documentation or article where adding this line has been mentioned.

Comment: We can't guess what your repository classes look like. The term is used to describe quite a lot of different things and many of the "repositories" aren't repositories at all. What this line does is register a concrete implementation for a generic interface. That's how eg `ILogger<>` is registered, without specifying an actual type. We can't guess how this is used in your code

Comment: BTW ASP.NET Core has no repositories. EF Core already implements repositories: a DbContext is a domain-level, multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work already. A DbSet is already a single entity Repository. We can't guess what the `Repository<>` class in your code does, or why

Comment: The purpose of register `IRepository<>` is to inject `IRepository<>`.

Comment: It will resolve all injection calls for any generic parameter you might use. You don't have to register them all explicitly.

Comment: @pana - quick question about the ef core already implements repository point you made - are you implying that in my service class I can directly make use of the dbcontext rather than using repository pattern?

Comment: @variable - [To Repository Or Not To Repository](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/237374/to-repository-or-not-to-repository)

Answer (score 0):

IRepository<> is known as unbound generic type

And For example，in my case:

```
public class User
    {
    }

    
    public class Product
    {

    }

public interface IServices<T>
    {
        Task<string> GetData();
        
    }
   

    public class Services<T> : IServices<T>
    {
        public Task<string> GetData()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(typeof(T).Name.ToString());
        }
    }
```

You could regist `IService<User>` and `IService<Product>` with `services.AddTransient(typeof(IServices<>), typeof(Services<>));`

Or

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IServices<User>), typeof(Services<User>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IServices<Product>), typeof(Services<Product>));
```

The first solution is more flexiable